# How to initialize a Groovybean?

Tags: groovy

I have a GroovyBean that I want to initialize. Basically, I´d like to transform one of the input parameters during construction of the object. In Java I would create a constructor and do the transformation in the constructor.

```
class JavaBean {

    int someInt;

    public JavaBean(SomeObject transformMe) {
        someInt = transform(transformMe) 

    }

    private int transform(SomeObject transformMe() {
        // Do some transformation
    }

}
```

This is a contrived example, but let´s say the transformation is something non-trivial.

My current solution in groovy is the following:

```
class GroovyBean {
    SomeObject transformMe
    @Lazy int someInt = transform(transformMe)

    def transform(SomeObject transformMe() {
        // Do some transformation
    }
}
```

To use the bean, I´d do this:

```
def bean = new GroovyBean(transformMe: anObjectToBeTransformed)
println bean.someInt
```

I want to avoid creating a constructor, as I´d like to keep the named parameter construction. I don´t really need to keep the transformMe-reference in the GroovyBean, it´s there only to be used when getting the someInt.

Is there a better way to initialize the GroovyBean without loosing the ability to use named parameters?

Comment: you can define a constructer for for groovybean, did you try something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd place the transformation code in the setter:

```
class WordWrapper {
    def String word

    void setReversed(String aReversedWord) {
        word = aReversedWord.reverse()
    }
}


assertEquals "cba", new WordWrappper(reversed: "abc").word
```

In my opinion this is more readable than using `@Lazy`.

Comment: Thanks, that would be a better solution.